# Why do my captures not work in .NET regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm parsing some text (admittedly HTML, but it's small stuff, and RegEx (should) do the job fine).
I'm trying to use some captures, but they just don't do what I think they should.

```
Match m = new Regex("(.*?)<br>(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)",
  RegexOptions.None).Match("word<br>stuff1/stuff2/stuff3")
CaptureCollection c = m.Captures;
```

To my mind, c should contain 4 entries; the stuff in each set of brackets.
But it doesn't. Regardless of whether I include any brackets, or all of them, or just the first, my CaptureCollection just contains the original string.

I am missing something about CaptureCollection? Or am I not capturing correctly in the regex?

Thanks for the solution (I'd vote up if I could)

Comment: I don't know about voting it up, but you can *accept* the solution--and should (assuming you're Mark Byers' answer).

Comment: Ah, so that's what the tick does.

Comment: Why not use the Html Agility Pack and eliminate all the regex issues? http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want m.Groups, not m.Captures.

Read about captures on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

do you have to escape your / with a \, like / ? im not sure, that's something i would try.

```
Match m = new Regex("(.*?)<br>(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*)",
  RegexOptions.None).Match("word<br>stuff1/stuff2/stuff3")
CaptureCollection c = m.Captures;
```